# jQuery post form with file to REST API

Tags: jquery, django, rest, file-upload, django-piston

I have a form with `enctype = "multipart / form-data"`. I need to send it to the REST API for uploading. The server is using Django and piston. Advise me how best to do this please. As of JavaScript (backbone) to serialize it into JSON with the file. Or is this not possible? Maybe I need to separately upload files, get their ID and then send them via REST only?

Comment: The jQuery AJAX methods do not support file uploads.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

You can have a plugin to do it, don't you think?

http://lagoscript.org/jquery/upload/demo?locale=en